# Upgrade ONNX model from version 9 to 11

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm working with an ONNX model that I need to quantize in order to reduce its size, for that I'm following the instructions on the official [documentation](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/performance/quantization.html):

```
import onnx
from onnxruntime.quantization import quantize_dynamic, QuantType

model_fp32 = 'path/to/the/model.onnx'
model_quant = 'path/to/the/model.quant.onnx'
quantized_model = quantize_dynamic(model_fp32, model_quant, weight_type=QuantType.QUInt8)
```

But when I run that I get the following warning:

```
WARNING:root:The original model opset version is 9, which does not support quantization. Please update the model to opset >= 11. Updating the model automatically to opset 11. Please verify the quantized model.
```

I tested the quantized model and did not work, it generates this error:

```
 INVALID_GRAPH : Load model from model_a2_quant.onnx failed:This is an invalid model. Error in Node:Upsample__477 : Op registered for Upsample is deprecated in domain_version of 11
```

What alternative do I have at this point to quantize the model?

I got the original model, in tensor flow, from this repo:  https://github.com/ciber-lab/pictor-ppe

And convert it to ONNX with this code:

```
# input and output
input_tensor = Input( shape=(input_shape[0], input_shape[1], 3) ) # input
num_out_filters = ( num_anchors//3 ) * ( 5 + num_classes )        # output

## Build and load the model 
model = yolo_body(input_tensor, num_out_filters)

weight_path = 'ONNX_demo/models/pictor-ppe-v302-a1-yolo-v3-weights.h5'

model.load_weights( weight_path )
tf.saved_model.save(model, "ONNX_demo/models/save_model")

# convert it to ONNX format: 

python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model "ONNX_demo/models/save_model" --output "ONNX_demo/models/model.onnx"
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have time to test your application, but I believe the problem happened when you try to convert the model to **ONNX** format.

By default, **tensorflow-onnx** use `opset-9` for the resulting **ONNX** graph. Probably is for that, that your model opset version is 9. Or because the version of **ONNX** installed on your system is this one.

When convert the model to ONNX format, you can specify the `opset` version, simply by typing the following argument to the command line:

```
--opset 11
```

In your case, the complete command line would look like:

```
python3 -m tf2onnx.convert \
           --saved-model "ONNX_demo/models/save_model" \
           --output "ONNX_demo/models/model.onnx" \
           --opset 11
```

In the official [**tensorflow-onnx** GitHub repository](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx), they said:

> By default we use the opset 9 to generate the graph. By specifying
> --opset the user can override the default to generate a graph with the desired opset. For example --opset 13 would create a onnx graph that
> uses only ops available in opset 13. Because older opsets have in most
> older cases fewer ops, some models might not convert on an opset.

Hope that I have helped in some way.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe it is the best solution. Please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thank you! If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know!